# Place the top left corner of an image on a specific pixel with imagemagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have an image of NxN size and an image of MxM, with N>M. I want to place the second on top of the first, but I want to do it on a specific pixel e.g.(10,15)

I installed imagemagick and start playing with it cli (planning to try with php later), but I could not find if there is something that I could use for this purpose or if it is possible by combining some commands.

So my question(s):

1. Is something like this possible with imagemagick?
2. If yes, how could I achieve it in command line imagemagick?
3. If yes, how could I achieve it with imagemagick in php?

Comment: Do you mean that the top, left corner of the MxM image should be on the pixel, or does M=1, or something else?

Comment: Yes I mean the top, left corner of the MxM image should be on a specific pixel of the NxN. That was my way of thinking how to place the MxM in specific position "inside" the NxN image.

Comment: have you considered using php gd? that is what I would use for this job

Comment: @Landon I haven't heard about it until now :). I 'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, I think php gd would be a good fit for this.  PHP gd is better integrated into php and works better in my opinion.  I use it for a host of things (resizing thumbnails most notably).  Your question seems very similar to placing a watermark on an image, ie one image is place on top of another and it is exported as a single raster image.  Here's a quick example for creating this watermark:

http://www.sitepoint.com/watermark-images-php/

This example exports it directly to the browser, but it can be easily modified to save the image locally to your file system.  Enjoy!

Comment: I accepted your answer because it does what I asked. Thank you!
However, I will go with imagemagick and compositeImage (Imagick::compositeImage).